# Elementary OS: How to create a clickable shellscript

Tags: terminal, shell-script, elementaryos

I am trying to make a shellscript clickable in a folder?

What I want is for the user to be able to click/double-click a shellscript in Files via the GUI and then have this shellscript open and run inside a graphical terminal.

I have tried making it executable (chmod +x myscript), but when I click it it just opens a terminal and not running the script.

I think I somehow associated shellscripts with Terminal app in an attempt to get this to work.  I probably need to remove this association somehow but cannot find any way of doing this in the UI.

When I right-click my script, it has a "Run" option but when I click this, nothing happens.

Update:
I found out that right click -> run actual does run the script although in a wrong path and with NO visual feedback what so ever. How do I make it run in a terminal?

Comment: FYI... I didn't realize this but just noticed an Elementary OS SO community that's in beta still, but seems like a good resource to utilize if you don't get much here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Does this mean I should just cross-post my question there? Or is cross posting frowned upon?

Comment: No, only if you get no attention from the bounty here that helps after it expires. There are people here that can potentially help with this too, just FYI only. Consider posting there or asking it to be migrated there after your bounty expires if you do not get any useful help here. I've never had to cross post but if I asked a question, set a bounty, and still didn't get a solution, I'd personally cross post regardless. If I was not allowed to delete my SU question if someone posts an answer that did not help, I'd reference this SU post in the question and say no one helped me there, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there is no way to force Elementary OS to run your shell script in a terminal window. Probably you should fill a bug.